# Changes of values in array are not detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, button

Here's my js code:

```
    // at first the three buttons have value 1
    var clicks = [1,1,1];

    // if (at least one button has value 2) {"button-next" = enabled}
    if (clicks.some(x => x == 1)) {
        document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = false;
    }
```

If at least one of the three values is `2`, `button-next` must be enabled.

---

With jQuery I managed to change the variabales to `2` at the first click (and the opacity to `1`) and back to `1` at the second click (and the opacity back to `0.5`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // BUTTON 1
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        if (clicks[0] == 1) {
            jQuery("#button1").css('opacity', '1');
            clicks[0] = 2;
        } else {
            jQuery("#button1").css('opacity', '0.5');
            clicks[0] = 1;
        }
    });

    // BUTTON 2
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        if (clicks[1] == 1) {
            jQuery("#button2").css('opacity', '1');
            clicks[1] = 2;
        } else {
            jQuery("#button2").css('opacity', '0.5');
            clicks[1] = 1;
        }
    });

    // BUTTON 3
    $("#button3").click(function(){
        if (clicks[2] == 1) {
            jQuery("#button3").css('opacity', '1');
            clicks[2] = 2;
        } else {
            jQuery("#button3").css('opacity', '0.5');
            clicks[2] = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on a button once the value changes, but the `button-next` remains disabled. It looks like the changes are not detected. I tried to change it manually like this:

```
var clicks = [1,2,1];
```

And I proved that these lines work:

```
    if (clicks.some(x => x == 1)) {
        document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = false;
    }
```

Because at that point `button-next` was enabled back. I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can do this all with some css and javascript together. Unless you have other code (not in your example) that is specific to each button, you could try something like this:

```js
function updateNextBtn() {
    if ($('.btn-clicked').length === 0) {
        $('#button-next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#button-next').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    // BUTTON 1
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        // Add or remove btn-clicked class
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-clicked');
        updateNextBtn();
    });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn.btn-clicked {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" class="btn">B1</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn">B2</button>
<button id="button3" class="btn">B3</button>
<button id="button-next" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
```

Comment: What does  `$('.btn-clicked').length === 0` mean?

Comment: The first part is a jquery selector: $(.btn-clicked'). This searches the document for all elements that have the "btn-clicked" class. This class is added to (or removed from if it already had the class) the buttons when clicked (using "toggleClass"). The selector will return something that is array-like, so it will have a "length" property that indicates how many elements were found with the ".btn-clicked" class. This way, we can find out if any buttons had been clicked. If none are clicked, $('.btn-clicked').length === 0 will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the snippet doesn't really align with the condition you've stated needing:

> If at least one of the three values is 2, button-next must be enabled.

`.some()` won't return `false` until the predicate returns `false` for every element.

To match your stated condition, the code should compare `x == 2` and swap the `disabled` values being set since the condition is now reversed:

```
if (clicks.some(x => x == 2)) {
    document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = true;
}
```

---

Though, a simpler change could be to use `.every()` instead of `.some()`.

> While all `clicks` are `1`, `button-next` is disabled.

```
if (clicks.every(x => x == 1)) {
// the rest as-is
```

---

A brief look at each:

```
[1, 1, 1].some(x => x == 1) // true (all are 1)
[1, 2, 1].some(x => x == 1) // true (1st and 3rd are 1, that's still some)
[2, 2, 2].some(x => x == 1) // false (none are 1)

[1, 1, 1].some(x => x == 2) // false (none are 2)
[1, 2, 1].some(x => x == 2) // true (2nd is 2)
[2, 2, 2].some(x => x == 2) // true (all are 2)

[1, 1, 1].every(x => x == 1) // true (all are 1)
[1, 2, 1].every(x => x == 1) // false (2nd is not 1)
[2, 2, 2].every(x => x == 1) // false (none are 1)
```

---

***Side note***

The snippet can be shortened with the `if..else` removed since `.some()` and `.every()` already provides a boolean value.

Here's the equivalent for each of the above snippets:

```
document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = !clicks.some(x => x == 2);
```

```
document.getElementById("button-next").disabled = clicks.every(x => x == 1);
```